# Datepicker inside dialog is overlapped

Tags: html, css, typescript, bootstrap-4, datepicker

So I'm having this issue:

[image: overlapping]

When I click on the datepicker input, the calendar opens overlapped. I know because if I set the dialog to display:none, the calendar is perfectly visible:

[image: calendar visible]

I've tried a lot with similar answers in StackOverflow but no none worked. All were related to z-index. I've also read the documentation and it specifies that the default z-index is 10 but it can be changed by setting zIndexOffset. This didn't work either. This is the code:

```
<dialog ng-if="controller.iView" class="rounded" style="position: fixed;width:750px;overflow-y: scroll;" id="feDialog">
  <div class="dialogHeader horizontalLayout">
    <span style="width:280px">Text:</span>
    <div class="flex"></div>
    <input type="text" style="width:100px; position: relative;" date-picker class="materialInput" ng-model="controller.date">
    <div class="materialButton colorButton" ng-click="controller.date = controller.getNowDate()">Hoy</div>
  </div>

  <div ng-if="controller.feDialogOpened" class="dialogContent flex verticalLayout">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="buttons horizontalLayout">
    <div class="materialButton" ng-click="controller.closeFeDialog();">Cancelar</div>
    <div class="flex"></div>
    <div class="materialButton disabledButton" ng-if="!controller.isValid()">Guardar</div>
    <div class="materialButton colorButton" ng-if="controller.isValid()" ng-click="controller.setState('state');f.closeFeDialog();">Guardar</div>
  </div>
</dialog>
```

datePicker directive is defined in Typescript as:

```
app.directive('datePicker', function() {
  /** Dev notes: in comments is an attemp to enable dynamic limits */
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    /**scope: {
      limits: "=?"
    },*/
    link: function (scope: ng.IScope, element: JQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes) {
      var view =  attrs.datePickerStartView || 'month';
      var minView = attrs.datePickerMinView || 'month';
      var format = attrs.datePickerFormat || 'dd/mm/yyyy';
      if (attrs.endDate === 'today') {
        attrs.endDate = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');
      }else if (attrs.endDate === 'none'){
        attrs.endDate = moment().add(1, 'years').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
      }else if(attrs.endDate != ''){
        attrs.endDate = attrs.endDate;
      }
      var endDate = attrs.endDate || new Date();

      if (attrs.startDate === 'today') {
        attrs.startDate = new Date();
      }
      var startDate = attrs.startDate || '01-01-1900';

      $(element)['datetimepicker']({
        format: format,
        endDate: endDate,
        startDate: startDate,
        autoclose: true,
        startView: view,
        minView: minView,
        language: 'es',
        todayBtn: attrs.unknownDate });

      // set input elements as readonly, so you cannot input free text.
      if (attrs.setReadonly) {
        $(element).find('input').attr('readonly', 'true');
      }
      /**
      scope.$watch(() => {
        return scope["limits"]
      }, (newVal,oldVal) => {
        if (!_.isEmpty(newVal)) {
          const min = scope["limits"].min
          const startDate = min ? moment(min).format('DD-MM-YYYY') : '01-01-1900'
          const max = scope["limits"].max
          const endDate = max ? moment(max).format('DD-MM-YYYY') : '01-01-2500'
          $(element)['datetimepicker']({
            endDate: endDate,
            startDate: startDate,
          });
        }
      })*/
    }
  };
});
```

The css classes are:

```
.dialogHeader{
  color: #2A323F;
  margin: 15px 15px 0;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.horizontalLayout{
  display         : flex;
  flex-direction  : row;
  align-items     : center;
}
```

Comment: Documentation I'm reading: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html

Comment: Hi, your script is fine, problem with css, please share css code best to provide js fiddle if possible

Comment: @MohammedYousuff what classes would you like to see? It's a project for a company so I cannot show all the code

Comment: this one class="dialogHeader horizontalLayout"

Comment: @MohammedYousuff done! I've just added that classes in the post.

Comment: What does your devtools say about the position of the <dialog... element? Because your inline styles would probably overrule the external CSS declarations, so your still stuck at the 'fixed' position. Just try to enable / disable elements and css values in your devtools to find out the problem easier

Comment: flex-direction: column, it should be fixed

Comment: @Hielke my devtools say the same I wrote in css and html...

Comment: @MohammedYousuff didn't work

Answer (score 0):

It's aiming in the dark without having some kind of working example, but the first thing comes up, is the positioning of your first element in the code...

```
<dialog ng-if="controller.iView" class="rounded" style="position: fixed;width:750px;overflow-y: scroll;" id="feDialog">
```

You have this element set to a fixed position. This means that the closest Relative parent sets the starting position of your presented code, which is in this case causing the wrong positioning IMO.

If not, please add some working code, showing the behaviour. In that case, I guess you've figured it out yourself at that point ;-)

Comment: what do you mean by working code? And what could be a fix to that? Changing the position of that element? I don't have much deep knowledge of html or css, only the basics... Sorry.

Comment: I mean that we, people who're trying to help you out, need a code sample which is working and showing the problem. Just a bit of code in a snippet and possibly with a demo on a 'fiddle' playground like jsfiddle.net. It's pure a design issue, so the rest is negligible.

Comment: What does your devtools say about the position of the <dialog... element? Because your inline styles would probably overrule the external CSS declarations, so your still stuck at the 'fixed' position

Comment: I can't how it through jsfiddle.net beause the controller is in Typescript. But if you need some other part of the code, I can post it. I only wrote the dialog code because the problem is in there.

Comment: my dialog element has position: fixed. But if I remove it, the bug doesn't fix.